# 1045 Error using mysql -u root

Tags: 14.04, mysql

i didn't find my answer on similiar questions so i ask my question here :

I've followed the instructions on [ApacheMySQLPHP page on help.ubuntu.com](http://ApacheMySQLPHP%20on%20help.ubuntu.com%20website)

but after the installation of MySQL & using the command `mysql -u root` on `sudo su -` mode it gave me this :

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What is the problem ?

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS if it's useful...

Thanks all.

**EDIT** : I reinstalled the package after i got the 1045 error when setting the password on setup process but no useful result...

**EDIT2** : The only change is *NO* to *YES*... :|

**EDIT3** : Do i need to reinstall or reset the password ?

Comment: Seems all too obvious to me: "access denied" + "using password: NO" -> you need to  insert a password. By the way: it should be "mysql -u root -p"

Comment: There is no change...

Answer (score 2):

When the MySQL server is installed you are usually asked to set a password for the root user.

So, when you're trying to login you should provide it as well with the `-p` option.

The correct command in your case is `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Same result after inserting the password

Answer (score 0):

After installing MySQL, you need to initial the password for root user by the command:

```
mysqladmin -u root password <newpass>
```

And to access you will have to use the command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: using the first command gave me the 1045 error.
with another error :


mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed

Comment: Have you started your mysql with `sudo service mysql start`?

Comment: It says that the service is running